# Why doesn't every random variable have null density function?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Can someone help me find the error in the following reasoning?

Let $Z$ be an absolutely continuous random variable.  I've been told that absolutely continuous random variable has $0$ probability in a single point $\mathbb{P}(Z=z)=0 ,\forall z \in \mathbb{R}$

but by definition of density $f_Z({z})=\mathbb{P}(Z=z)$

Hence $ f_Z({z})=0$, that is any absolutely continuous random variable has null density function? I know the result is absurd, I just can't find the error in the reasoning

Comment: Cite for that "definition of density"?

Comment: Because the probability density function, unlike the probability mass function, is not defined to be the probability of a specific point.

Comment: @Shubham Johri In my lectures they have told me that the density function is the law of the random variable calculated in a borelian set formed by a single point: $P_Z({z})=P(Z^{−1}(\{z\}))=P(Z=z):=f_Z(z)$ . So is this only valid for a discrete random variable?

Answer (score 1):

For a discrete random variable $Z$, the probability mass function $p_Z(z) = P(Z=z)$ is a complete description of the distribution. For a continuous random variable $Z$, the probabilities of single points no longer define the distribution. Instead one has to consider the probabilities of intervals. Usually one defines the cumulative probability function
$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z\le z).
$$
Then, the probability density function is defined as the derivative of $F_Z$, that is $f_Z(z) = \frac{\mathrm d F_Z}{\mathrm dz}(z)$.

This then allows to compute probabilites of intervals as
$$
P(a < Z \le b) = P(Z\le b) - P(Z\le a) = F_Z(b) - F_Z(a) = \int_a^b f_Z(z) \mathrm\,dz.
$$
Note that this is an integral over density values, not a sum of probabilities!

While probabilities are always $\le 1$, we can very well have densities $>1$. However, the area under the graph of $f_Z$, which is the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz$ is always equal to $1$.

Comment: Can I conclude that when we  talk about "cumulative density functions", we don't care if the variable is discrete or assolutely continuous, $P(X<a)=F_X(a) $ always works; but with the density function $P(X=a)=f_X(a)$ is only true for discrete variables? I guess I shouldn't even use the name probability function for the discrete case, but pmf

Comment: However, the name pmf , makes me think in something continuous since mass is usually a continuous thing, so I don't know why they call it that way